# UE5.0.3 Crash when stopping PIE after Ejecting from Character

Tags: crash, unreal-engine5

Unreal crashes when stopping the editor after ejecting from a character. Only happens for me and no other developers on the team. Version control is Perforce and I no pending changes.

Opening a level that another developer is working on and does not have the issue with causes the crash for me.

I'm open to any solutions.

**Edit:** Started happening on a new level with just random occurrence, can't find anything to single out as a cause as it may or may not happen with identical situations.

```
KERNELBASE
UnrealEditor_Core!ReportAssert() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsPlatformCrashContext.cpp:1807]
UnrealEditor_Core!FWindowsErrorOutputDevice::Serialize() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsErrorOutputDevice.cpp:76]
UnrealEditor_Core!FOutputDevice::LogfImpl() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Misc\OutputDevice.cpp:61]
UnrealEditor_Core!AssertFailedImplV() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Misc\AssertionMacros.cpp:149]
UnrealEditor_Core!FDebug::AssertFailed() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Misc\AssertionMacros.cpp:534]
UnrealEditor_Core!FMsg::LogfImpl() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp:75]
UnrealEditor_MessageLog!FMessageLogListingModel::AddMessageInternal() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Developer\MessageLog\Private\Model\MessageLogListingModel.cpp:68]
UnrealEditor_MessageLog!FMessageLogListingModel::AddMessages() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Developer\MessageLog\Private\Model\MessageLogListingModel.cpp:89]
UnrealEditor_Core!FMessageLog::Flush() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\MessageLog.cpp:218]
UnrealEditor_Core!FMessageLog::~FMessageLog() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\MessageLog.cpp:109]
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::EndPlayMap() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\PlayLevel.cpp:436]
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::Tick() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorEngine.cpp:2097]
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd!UUnrealEdEngine::Tick() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdEngine.cpp:474]
UnrealEditor_LyraEditor!ULyraEditorEngine::Tick() [D:\_Work\Stuart_Supraworld\Supraworld\Source\LyraEditor\LyraEditorEngine.cpp:34]
UnrealEditor!FEngineLoop::Tick() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\LaunchEngineLoop.cpp:5215]
UnrealEditor!GuardedMain() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Launch.cpp:183]
UnrealEditor!GuardedMainWrapper() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:147]
UnrealEditor!LaunchWindowsStartup() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:283]
UnrealEditor!WinMain() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:330]
UnrealEditor!__scrt_common_main_seh() [d:\a01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
kernel32
ntdll
```

I've tried:
-Verifying the Editor
-Modifying VS both removing/adding SDK, IDE Support etc,
-Removing named actors in logs (just selects another actor and still crashes)
-Removing all Binaries/Intermediate folders
-Rebuilding entire project
-Reconciling Perforce
-Fresh install of GPU-Nvidia drivers
-and a bunch of other little things.

Just throw solutions at me I'll try anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else finds themselves in a similar position I managed to fix the issue by basically deleting my local copy of the depot and redownloading it.

Must have been a dodgy file somewhere locally that was screwing with everything.

Not that I would have liked to download another 50,000 assets but it seemed to fix the issue.